# How to filter allele frequency VEP with bcftools?

Tags: bcftools

I have a VEP annotated VCF file, and I wish to use bcftools to filter it. bcftools work very well on standard VCF fields, but I'm not able to make it work on VEP fields.

For example, the following command would report "not defined in the vcf header" (it's not a standard VCF field but part of the VEP fields in the VCF file). `split-vep` is a VEP plugin offered by bcftools.

```
bcftools +split-vep MyFile.vcf -i 'gnomAD_exomes_AF<0.01'
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Now, please also give us a file we can test on. Try to make it as minimal as possible while reproducing the error. Note that if the field isn't actually included in the headers, then the VCF is not valid, and bcftools won't know how to deal with it. You might, however, be able to script something, but for that we will need to see at least some part of the file.